# Is there a reason why Pisa/Florence hostels are much more expensive around the 5th May?

Tags: italy, hostels

I'm flying into Pisa on Fri. 5th may, and looking at hostel prices on hostelworld, I'm seeing 30-40 euro in Pisa and 50-80 euro (!!) in Florence. I'm used to paying 20-25 euro for hostels in western Europe. Is there something happening in Italy on the 5th may, or are hostels in Italy just more expensive than I'm used to?

Comment: They've definitely gone up in Thailand, Japan, and Taiwan. Especially for weekends and holidays. Could've gone up worldwide.

Comment: Did you check the prices in Florence (and Pisa) a few weeks later? Did you check prices in other countries?

Comment: May 8th is a public holiday in France and an other countries in Europe (for the Easternmost ones it’s May 9th), which this year makes the May 6th to 8th a long week-end, which may increase the number of visitors and raise prices. But did you compare with prices in the days/weeks before and after? Is this specific to this date or is it just a more general price inflation?

Comment: Also it’s within school holidays in part of France and possibly other countries.